# Reauthenticate after Session has expired in volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am new to the volley library and try to figure out what is the best way to do the following.

My REST Api uses Basic Authentication first and if succeed they return a Access Token to use from that point. Because my Acces Token can expire, this is a requirement.

1. I want to call my api method `http://myserver/test`
2. I get back a `401 (Unauthorized)`.
3. I want to call `http://myserver/auth` using basic authentication
4. I get back a Access Token
5. Set the header to `"Authentication: Session " + AccessToken`
6. I want to "retry" the request to `http://myserver/test`.

### Update

So basically what i want to do is. If a request failed with a given status code, i want to do a other request and after that retry the first one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so basically u wanna try again if session expires? so u try for service or asynctask

Comment: why it matters "for service or asynctask"? Lets say i open my app again and it was still running but my server was restarted or the session has expired.

Comment: yup when u session is expired then every hit or api call to server will provide u some error saying reauth ...that time u can reauthicate and get token

Comment: Have you figure out how to solve this problem? I'm stuck with the same problem you described here and so far I can't find any working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a similar approach using Volley.
 Have listener from where the request is sent., Everytime when you get response **check for session**, if **session is expired**, *save existing listeners* temporarily.

Create new listeners & get Token, if success, resend request with `oldTemp` Listeners, so the request is sent back to original request.

[image: Volley handle session expired]

*[Working app in PlayStore with similar approach.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MobiGyaan)*

Comment: I have working code, it's kind of huge, but will try to share.

Comment: Any luck on sharing some of the code? I'm currently working on this same problem.

Comment: @Zammbi Nope, OP said he will do it by himself, so dropped it.

Comment: MehulAkoliya I have updated the answer, may be you can get some idea. Will be posting the working code in few days.